# Use a variable instead of UNION query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a query with a variable criteria. Is there anyway to do the below without using the Union, instead using a list of dates in another table?

```
SELECT
'2014-03-03' AS SnapshotDate
,T2.Pre_PPI_Cycle
,SUM(ISNULL(T2.Pre_PPI_Balance, 0))AS Pre_Balance
,COUNT(ISNULL(T2.Account_Number, 0)) AS Pre_Volume
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Account_Number 
ORDER BY Account_Number, SnapshotDate DESC) AS ROW
FROM #TABLE_1 AS T2
WHERE T2.SnapshotDate <= '2014-03-03'
GROUP BY T2.SnapshotDate, T2.Pre_PPI_Cycle, Account_Number
UNION
SELECT
'2014-03-04' AS SnapshotDate
,T2.Pre_PPI_Cycle
,SUM(ISNULL(T2.Pre_PPI_Balance, 0))AS Pre_Balance
,COUNT(ISNULL(T2.Account_Number, 0)) AS Pre_Volume
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Account_Number 
ORDER BY Account_Number, SnapshotDate DESC) AS ROW
FROM #PPI_3 AS T2
WHERE T2.SnapshotDate <= '2014-03-04'
GROUP BY T2.SnapshotDate, T2.Pre_PPI_Cycle, Account_Number
```

**EDIT**

Thanks for the help so far - just to clarify - this is the code I now have.

```
SELECT
 T2.Capture_Date
,T1.Pre_PPI_Cycle
,SUM(ISNULL(T1.Pre_PPI_Balance, 0))AS Pre_Balance
,COUNT(ISNULL(T1.Account_Number, 0)) AS Pre_Volume
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.Account_Number 
 ORDER BY T1.Account_Number, T1.SnapshotDate DESC) AS ROW
FROM 
#PPI_3 AS T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT CHILD.Capture_Date
FROM #DATES AS CHILD
WHERE CHILD.Capture_Date <= '2014-03-04') T2
ON T2.Capture_Date = T1.SnapshotDate
GROUP BY T2.Capture_Date, T1.SnapshotDate, T1.Pre_PPI_Cycle, T1.Account_Number
```

I've mentioned below in the comments that I'm looking to change the date '2014-03-04' to a list of dates which is kept in the table #DATES. For example if the date <= '2014-03-03' it returns 32 records. If the date <= '2014-03-04' it returns 55 records. What I would like is for the total query to return 87 records. That's the part I'm struggling with!

Thanks for everyone's help so far - feel like we're making progress!

Thanks, Sam

Comment: What I want to do is replace the dates (2014-03-03, 2014-03-04, etc) with a list of dates held in another table.

Comment: For example in the above queries the first one returns 32 accounts where the date is <= '2014-03-03' and then the second query returns 55 accounts where the date is <= '2014-03-04' so I want the query to return 87 rows in total. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @mydate smalldatetime

set @mydate = '2014-03-03';

SELECT
    '2014-03-03' AS SnapshotDate
    ,T2.Pre_PPI_Cycle
    ,SUM(ISNULL(T2.Pre_PPI_Balance, 0))AS Pre_Balance
    ,COUNT(ISNULL(T2.Account_Number, 0)) AS Pre_Volume
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Account_Number ORDER BY Account_Number, SnapshotDate      DESC) AS ROW
FROM #TABLE_1 AS T2
INNER JOIN ( SELECT T2.ID, myDate
             FROM #TABLE_1 AS T2
            WHERE T2.SnapshotDate <= @mydate
           ) x
           ON x.myDate = T2.SnapshotDate
           AND x.ID = T2.ID
GROUP BY T2.SnapshotDate, T2.Pre_PPI_Cycle, Account_Number
```

OR

```
SELECT
     '2014-03-03' AS SnapshotDate
    ,T2.Pre_PPI_Cycle
    ,SUM(ISNULL(T2.Pre_PPI_Balance, 0))AS Pre_Balance
    ,COUNT(ISNULL(T2.Account_Number, 0)) AS Pre_Volume
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Account_Number ORDER BY Account_Number, SnapshotDate DESC) AS ROW
FROM #TABLE_1 AS T2
WHERE T2.SnapshotDate IN ( SELECT myDate
          FROM #TABLE_1 AS T2
          WHERE T2.SnapshotDate <= '2014-03-03' )
GROUP BY T2.SnapshotDate, T2.Pre_PPI_Cycle, Account_Number
```

---

Based on your latest update. I would do the following as its a bit easier:

```
SELECT
 T1.Capture_Date
,T1.Pre_PPI_Cycle
,SUM(ISNULL(T1.Pre_PPI_Balance, 0))AS Pre_Balance
,COUNT(ISNULL(T1.Account_Number, 0)) AS Pre_Volume
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.Account_Number 
 ORDER BY T1.Account_Number, T1.SnapshotDate DESC) AS ROW
FROM #PPI_3 AS T1
WHERE T1.Capture_Date IN ( 
    SELECT CHILD.Capture_Date 
    FROM #DATES AS CHILD 
    WHERE CHILD.Capture_Date <= '2014-03-04')
GROUP BY T1.Capture_Date, T1.SnapshotDate, T1.Pre_PPI_Cycle, T1.Account_Number
```

Comment: THe correct logic would take into account the condition in the original query:  `T2.SnapshotDate <= '2014-03-04'`.

Comment: What I don't understand is how to get the '2014-03-03' as a variable - I don't want to hard code it in.

Comment: Also in the first example how does the subquery T2.SnapshotDate connect back to the #Table_1?

Comment: ok. I have changed the first query example in include a single date variable and also updated the INNER JOIN clause. The join now finds all the rows with a date you are interested in. It may be easier to remove the entire INNER JOIN statement and simply include a WHERE statement just above the GROUP BY: WHERE T2.SnapshotDate <= @mydate

Comment: Could you look at my edit as I've pasted in the code I now have along with a further description of what I'm trying to achieve to try and make things a little clearer! Thank you so much for your help so far!